# gwt requestfactory view database

Tags: java, database, gwt, requestfactory

relating to the `request factory` in `gwt`.

How / Where can I view the entity records in the database (without using any code)?

Comment: Do you mean you're persisting the entities in some database? And you want to query the data?

Comment: the official tutorial on request factory left me with a lot of unanswered questions... I have no idea how the entities you define are stored. Are they in a database? Do they exist after a server reboot?

But my main questions is, how can I see these entities (like I would  in a normal sql database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequestFactory is about sending entities and other objects, along with actions to be performed on them, between your clients and your server. Once the objects arrive on the server, it's up to you to manage their persistence. You can use JPA, JDO, Objectify, Morphia, etc. depending whether you want to use a SQL DB, AppEngine Datastore, MongoDB, etc.

RequestFactory is very comparable to GWT-RPC if that can make it clearer for you.